# Chaining multiple RxJava2 operations using Room and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, rx-java2, android-room

Some background: I'm new to RxJava and I'm trying to make a feature in the app that will work offline and sync when there is network. I'm trying to chain multiple operations but I'm not well versed in how to chain different types like Completable, Maybe and Observable together.

Here are the list of operations that need to be done in the order after user adds or updates some data:

1. Update data on local db, just set the status to **syncing**, using Room here.
2. Upload the file to Firebase storage.
3. Get the file url and update the data to Firebase Database.
4. Update data on local db, set the status to **synced**.

Here are the methods for each operation:

**Update local db:**

```
private Completable setStatus(Entity entity, Entity.Status status){
    entity.setStatus(status);
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> localDataStore.updatePersonalPlace(personalPlaceEntity));
}
```

**Upload file to FirebaseStorage, using [Rx2Firebase](https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase)**

```
RxFirebaseStorage.putBytes(storageRef, bytes); // returns a Maybe<TaskSnapshot>
```

**Set data in firebase database**

```
RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(dataRef, model); // returns a Completable
```

I've tried

```
setStatus(...)
  .toObservable()
  .map(o -> uploadFile())
  .map(fileUrl -> updateFirebaseDatabase(fileUrl))
  .doOnNext(() -> setStatus(..) ) // set status to synced
  .subscribe(() -> Timber.d("Data updated", 
               t -> setStatus(..)); // set status back to what it was on error
```

But this doesn't work and I think I don't really understand the fundamentals of how to chain these operations. None of the operations after toObservable get called.

I've also tried to convert the maybe to a completable and chain them using `Completable.andThen` but I'm not sure how to do that correctly and I need the fileUrl returned to update the firebase database.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to what should I use here. It's a fairly simple task which feels a lot complicated right now, maybe my approach is horribly wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the content of `subscribe`? Do you handle error? Maybe some action need to be on a specific thread and crash.

Comment: Updated in the question. Just logging in case of success and setting the status back to original in case of failure so entity can be synced later.

Answer (score 2):

I add some comments to your code:

```
setStatus(...) // completable => (onError|onComplete)?
  .toObservable() // => will call (onError|onComplete)? (beacause of the nature of completable)
  .map(o -> uploadFile()) // never call because no item is emitted (completable...)
  .map(fileUrl -> updateFirebaseDatabase(fileUrl)) // never call too
  .doOnNext(() -> setStatus(..) ) // set status to synced // never call too
  .subscribe(..)
```

You have to change your `Completable` for a `Single` and returning something like `true`.

Comment: I see. So using Single will solve this? Also, is using map operator here the best approach? At the end I get a `Single<Completable>` as `RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(dataRef, model)` returns a Completable.

Comment: Update: Using Single, the file gets uploaded but the firebase database call is never made. File upload call returns a Maybe.

Comment: setStatus must return something like Single<Boolean>

Comment: At the moment it returns Single<Integer>.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, it's the same as in the question: `RxFirebaseStorage.putBytes(storageRef, bytes);`

Comment: I solved it by using flatMap for uplooadFile and flatMapCompletable for updateFirebaseDatabase. I have a better understanding of how flatMap works thanks to [this talk by Dan Lew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ).

Answer (score 1):

Set status returns a `Completable`, which will only ever call `onComplete` or `onError`. Your `map` and `doOnNext` never get called because it never emits any items. What you probably want use `doOnComplete` or look into using `concatArray`, `startWith` or `concatWith` that can chain Completables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers from [Kevinrob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300318/1262089) and [cwbowron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46299795/1262089) I was able to figure out what was going wrong.

setStatus now returns a Single:

```
private Single<Integer> setStatus(Entity entity, Entity.Status status){
    entity.setStatus(status);
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> localDataStore.updatePersonalPlace(personalPlaceEntity));
}
```

This returns a completable which:

1. Sets the entity status as syncing in local db.
2. Converts a bitmap to byte array.
3. Uploads the photo on Firebase Storage.
4. Gets the photo url.
5. Updates the data on Firebase Database.
6. Finally updates the entity status as synced in local db.

   ```
   return setPlaceStatusSingle(entity, Entity.Status.SYNCING)
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                       .toObservable()
                       .map(integer -> BitmapUtils.convertBitmapToByteArray(entity.getPhoto()))
                       .doOnNext(bytes -> Timber.d("Converted bitmap to bytes"))
                       .flatMap(bytes -> RxFirebaseStorage.putBytes(fileRef, bytes).toObservable())
                       // Using flatmap to pass on the observable downstream, using map was a mistake which created a Single<Observable<T>> 
                       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                       .doOnNext(taskSnapshot -> Timber.d("Uploaded to storage"))
                       .map(taskSnapshot -> taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString()) // Firebase stuff, getting the photo Url
                       .flatMapCompletable(photoUrl -> { 
                           Timber.d("Photo url %s", photoUrl);
                           model.setPhotoUrl(photoUrl);
                           return RxFirebaseDatabase.setValue(ref, model);
                       })
                       // Passes the Completable returned from setValue downstream
                       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                       .doOnComplete(() -> {
                           entity.setStatus(Entity.Status.SYNCED);
                           entity.setPhotoUrl(model.getPhotoUrl());
                           localDataStore.updateEntity(entity);
                       })
                       .doOnError(throwable -> onErrorUpdatingEntity(entity, throwable));
   ```